# Visual Studio 2019 Git shows "commit --allow-empty-message --file=-" message on commit & push, after new update installed. no more commit & push

Tags: visual-studio-2019, git-commit, git-push

After updating my visual studio 2019(v 16.9.5), when I do a git commit & push, a message appears above the "git changes" window with this content "commit --allow-empty-message --file=-" and the process fails and stuck at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to your windows "Credential Manager" and update the repo credentials that you use for your git and simply update your password or remove the credentials. If you remove the credential your git manager plugin(in any IDE you are developing in) will ask you to enter the credentials again.